# Why async code fails in Tampermonkey on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

This code:

```
(async ()=>{
    let i=0;
    while (1) {
        await sleep(1);
        console.log(i++);
    }
})();
function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve();
        },ms);
    })
}
```

works correctly in browser, but in Tampermonkey userscript fails with:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at eval (userscript.html?id=4ef091f1-f006-441d-bf58-4bd22750f636:24)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sleep (userscript.html?id=4ef091f1-f006-441d-bf58-4bd22750f636:23)
    at eval (userscript.html?id=4ef091f1-f006-441d-bf58-4bd22750f636:18)
```

after nearly 3k iterations.

I think promises don't work correctly in Tampermonkey.

Used chrome 74, Tampermonkey 4.8.41

Any ideas?

**Update:**
The bug is not in promise. This code fails too:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function doWork(){
        console.log(doWork.i++);
        setTimeout(doWork,1);
    }
    doWork.i=0;
    doWork();

})();
```

In opera and FF all of it works perfectly.

**Update:**
Infinite loops are only for examples. But it was tested for working and memory leaks in node,chrome, FF.
I think, it happens with many(>4k for me) asynchronous calls in one Tampermonkey script. I'll try give some another code without infinite loops soon.

Comment: Your code works fine in Firefox+Tampermonkey 4.9

Comment: It seems in FF works, i have tryed recently too. Thanks for running script.

Comment: Have this issue too with `setTimeout` in Chrome + Tampermonkey, either a Tampermonkey bug or Chrome bug.

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome + Tampermonkey and I see no reason why it shouldn't (other than a bug in either one as already noted).

Comment: The problem is that the code (both sets) is chewing up memory until the sandbox it is in crashes.  This happens sooner in some environments but is abominably bad code irregardless.  Don't write useless infinite loops. And use `setInterval()` if more than one iteration is planned.

Comment: Can you tell me, why it chews memory?

Fist one is only for example but it works without memory leaks for days in other js evoroments(tested on node, chrome, ff)

Second one is not bad-practice and is used often, when you need different(random for example) intervals.

Comment: Please avoid from adding SOLVED and similar language to the title of the question.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question for more info.

Comment: Yes, i'll delete this tag.

Comment: Hello Moderator,

I think it is not duplicate, please read it perfectly. The question is not about infinite loops.

And i want answer my question, by can't do it. Why? 
Is it a good practice to post my solution this way?

Comment: This is a Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961199

Comment: @derjanb, that bug seems to be about the `with` statement.  How does that apply to this OP's (infinitely) looping code?

Comment: @BrockAdams OP says that the code runs fine outside Tampermonkey (because there is no sandbox which is using 'with') and at Tampermonkey Firefox. My repro at the issue report also somehow is a infinite loop. It seems that loops are required to trigger this Chrome issue. And when it happens then exactly the same error is thrown.

Comment: @derjanb, it's not a system issue.  It's a memory/stack issue.  the OP's code eventually fails in all environments, it just takes longer depending on the memory available (which is less for the default Tampermonkey instance).

Comment: @BrockAdams A stack error does not throw type errors: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" but "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: @derjanb, usually so.  Nevertheless, the code continues to run until it has chewed up the allotted memory, then it fails.

Comment: @BrockAdams Second one works for weeks on my node server. It is normal practise to do infinite setTimeout.
fist one don't chew too. But inf. loops in js is not good practice, I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Tampermonkey for chrome sandbox bug.
(maybe caused by this [chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961199))
This code fixes it, untill issue will not be fixed in TM or Chrome.
I used another injection method:

```
var scriptText=`
    /* some code fails with this bug */
`;
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode(scriptText);
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript);
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```